# VB connection build and run on IIS express and local IIS

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, runtime-error, local

compile , then run VB code in visual studio result in below error , compile is an IIS

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false"

Comment: This usually happens when you are trying to set a value in your `web.config` that the parent container says cannot be changed. The parent container can be changed to allow it to be set in your `web.config`. Which setting to look for and change will be hard without more information

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem.

1. in the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
2. in the features window, look for "Internet Information Services"
3. Click: "World Wide Web Services"
4. Click: "Application Development Features"
5. Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI

If this method does not work, you can still try this:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click the server name in the tree on the left
3. Right hand pane, Management section, double click Configuration Editor
4. At the top, choose the section `system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication`
5. Right hand pane, click Unlock Section
6. At the top, choose the section `system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication`
7. Right hand pane, click Unlock Section